# How to setup Robolectric in Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android, tdd, junit4, robolectric

I am a Android developer and a TDD passionate. Recently, I learned about a new testing framework, Robolectric, which seems to be far superior to the JUnit 3 solution Android Studio provides by default. I wanted to setup it, but after numerous tries, failures and `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` I achieved nothing.

Here is my question:

How do I setup, step-by-step, the Robolectric testing framework on Andoird Studio 1.0? Please note:

- I do not need vague ideas or hints. I need a complete solution.
- I can not provide any code from my previous tries, as it is useless and already deleted.

The setup of this framework is very problematic and has numerous issues among different versions of Android Studio and IntelliJ. I browsed all of them, but to no avail. I need help from someone who succeded in using the framework on Android Studio 1.0.

Comment: When you did a search on `robolectric "android studio"` on your favorite search engine, what did you learn?

Comment: I learned around 10 different workarounds and ways to setup it, none of which worked. It incluced editing Gradle script, editing iml files of the project as well as meddling with the order libraries are compiled into the project. None of these worked. I am looking for someone who already got Robolectric to run on AS 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Over those few months the setup process of Robolectric for Android Studio improved quite a bit, so before trying the below, 'long' approach, just try the official guide [here](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/)! :-)

---

Ok, I managed to setup it! It is very tricky and not fully compatible with the newest Gradle 1.0.0, but it is working like a charm!

My solution is based mainly on [this tutorial](http://raptordigital.blogspot.com/2014/02/test-driven-development-with.html)

So, your build.gradle file (the "inner" one, inside the project's folder) should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '[your app id]'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest') // This one is important, make sure to avoid typos in it, or you will get empty tests
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'

    // ================== TESTING LIBRARIES ======================
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    androidTestCompile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.50'
}

robolectric {
    // configure the set of classes for JUnit tests
    include '**/*Test.class' //Make sure you call all your test classes according to this expression!!!

    // configure max heap size of the test JVM
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}

apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../app/src/main/java'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testDebug.exec')

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

}
```

It looks alot like the "outer" build.gradle file, but all this stuff has to be right here.

Some of the elements my be unneeded here, but I did my best to cut it down to the core part. After you so this, a Test class is created like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;


@Config(emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18) //Those are required as the framework does not yet support higher API levels
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RoboDummyTest {

    @Test
    public void testActivityFound() {
        Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();

        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
    }
}
```

All data is stub of course :-)

Finally, the tests are run by typing `gradlew test` into the terminal inside Android Studio. The results will be saved to a html file inside the `build` directory of your project.

I hope this will be helpful to anyone planning on setting Robolectric with Android Studio 1.0. Happy TDDing!

EDIT:
The author of the blog post I used to write the answer, Kvandermast, was as kind as to provide the below link to a repository containing a working example, updated every Android Studio update:
https://github.com/kvandermast/my-robolectric-app

Comment: I still get a `ClassNotFoundException` error for every test class when trying to run a `./gradlew clean build` with this setup. My setup is identical to the one described in that tutorial you posted, with src/main and src/androidTest for the directory structure. Any idea what gives?

Comment: What class is not found?

Comment: All of the test classes aren't found... pretty sure that's because they're not even being built for some reason.

Comment: These two lines:

`include '**/*Test.class'`
`androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')`

Make sure you got them right

Comment: Yeah, definitely have those, but still not working :(

Comment: But did you edit them to match your project? Are you naming the test classes so that they end with Test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67264/discussion-between-mtrewartha-and-kelevandos).

Comment: Did you modifu your test class accordingly? Make sure to remove the extends part in the topmost declaration AND remove the constructor matching that extendes super class.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out all different workarounds that I have been able to find, got some to work and some did not work at all.

But yesterday I found one that actually worked without too much effort and does it so quite nicely: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/

This approach is based on a another gradle robolectric plugin, but it also includes an android studio plugin that handles the classpath problems in a neat way.

Best solution for this that I have found! It works almost as if out-of-box.